# Ajax call html page contain JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I load an html page containing a jquery function with Ajax.

Page A calls Page B with ajax. In Page B, some HTML is generated and contains some jquery functions.  But I think he tries to run the jquery on page B. I get errors `$ is undefined` and my jquery source are in Page A.

Can I prevent the execution of javascript on Page B?

Here is my call from Page A:

```
var options = {
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSubmit: function () {

                $('#' + s_Target_Response).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                });

            },
            success: function (response) {

                $("#loading").offset({ top: 1, left: 1 });

                $('#loading').hide();

                Init();

                $('#' + s_Target_Response).html(response);
                $('#' + s_Target_Response).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            }
        };

         // pass options to ajaxForm 
        $('#' + s_Target_Form).ajaxForm(options);

        $('#' + s_Target_Form).submit();
```

Comment: What is "s_Target_Response" and what is Init() in this case?

Comment: do you realy want to place a whole html file into an existing html file? I thnk you want just some contents of page b right? so take the contents of b into a jquery selector and filter out the container, and only that container, that contains what you want to display

Comment: Page B is an asp.net page and i execute some functions in server side. Page B only dump server side results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the execution of the script on Page B; and since you dont have jQuery defined on page B; Wrap your scripts in

```
if( typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' ){
  //page B scripts
}
```

Comment: Now i get 'jQuery is not defined'